# Select 2 doesn't show the Selected Options. (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.1, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 jquery plugin, and laravel form model binding to render the data from the server. 
While everything else works fine, it doesn't rendered the tags that has been attached to the post as selected option.

there must be something which I'm unaware of, here's my view part.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('tag_list','Tags:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('tag_list[]', $tags,null,['id'=>'tag_list', 'class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}

</div>

// This is the select 2 script
$('#tag_list').select2({
    'placeholder':'Choose Tags',
    tags:true,
    tokenSeparators:[",", " "],
    createTag:function(newTag){
        return{
            id:'new:' + newTag.term,
            text:newTag.term + '(new)'
        };
    }
});
```

And this is a getTagListAtrribute function in Article model

// This is the getTagListAttribute function

```
 public function getTagListAttribute(){
        return $this->tags->lists('post_id')->all();
    }
```

And I load the edit form from the controller like this:

```
public function article_edit($slug){
        // fetch the articles.
        //$article = DB::table('articles')->where('slug',$slug)->first();

        $article = Article::where('slug',$slug)->first();

        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($article->title);
        die();*/
        $tags = DB::table('tags')->lists('name','tag_id');
        $categories=DB::table('categories')->lists('category_name','category_id');

        return view('admin.pages.edit', compact('article','tags','categories'));
    }
```

I just want the tags which are associated with article be selected while the page loads, and which I've been unable of. So I'm in the need of help.

Comment: This may be just me not noticing the obvious, but where are you setting values as selected?

Comment: the form model binding should be taking care of that, when I use null as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe it would have helped visually if you had the `Form::model` code in the code snippet as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did mention that I'm using form model binding. I could edit the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since you have tagged the question as `laravel-5.1`. There are some changes been made to the `lists` method.

In Laravel 5.0.* it returned just the plain array of `keys` and/or `values` that you pass in the `lists` method. [More info here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)

In Laravel 5.1.*, it returns a Collection object. [More Info - Just the code documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_lists)

So, the solution that you are looking for is:

In controller, do this:

```
$tags = DB::table('tags')->lists('name','tag_id')->toArray();
```

Or in the view file, do this:

```
{!! Form::select('tag_list[]', $tags->toArray(), null,['id'=>'tag_list', 'class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
```

And that should do the trick for you.

**EDIT 1:**

Remove `all()` method from `getTagsListAttribute()`. That is not at all required.

Why are you using `DB` Facade for querying the `tags` table ? Since you have already established the relationship, you are unnecessarily executing the `SQL Statements`. Avoid that as much as you can.

You should get it by simply doing this:

```
$tags = $article->tags;
```

**EDIT 2:**

Are you sure that you have `tag_id` column in `tags` table ? I doubt that.  I guess that must be a typo.. By mistakenly, you must have typed `tag_id` instead of `id`. Cross verify it for the confirmation.

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding. Cheers.

Comment: I thank you for your answer, yes I do have tag_id, I generally use the convention like this to avoid the confusions of multiple ids. Let me check, if that does the trick. And $article->tags will fetch only the associated tags, but here I want all the tags to be passed on the view. So I'm using DB:: query.

Comment: I'm using laravel version 5.1.23, and when I do the toArray() on the $tags variable, it says, Call to member function toArray() in Non-Object. I guess this shouldn't be the error. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Set select form tag like this

```
{!! Form::select('tag_list', $tags, $selected, ['id'=>'tag_list', 'name'=>'tag_list[]','class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
```

Pass the ids to be selected as array in third ($selected).
So, if

```
  $tags = ['1'=>'one', '2'=>'Two', '3'=>'Three']
```

and you want One and Three selected, pass these ids as an array to the form select as the third parameter.

so, $selected = [1,3];

Comment: I want those selected values from the controller, and the basic reason behind that getTagListAttribute() function is to fetch the associated tags with a particular post_id.